# Strange media query behavior

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've come across some strange behavior which I cannot for the life of me figure out.

I have a fluid grid design with a number of media queries (7 to be exact).
I have no pretence that what I'm doing is best practice so for kicks I made the 7 queries.

For brevity I'll only paste three queries, the one that is the problem and the one right before and the one immediately after.

**The one before**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) and (max-width: 1189px) {
    body {
        color: PaleTurquoise;
    }    
}
```

**The troubling one**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1190px) and (max-width: 1409px) {
    body {
        color: lime;
    }
}
```

**The one immediately after**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1410px) {
    body {
        max-width: 2000;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

So what's happening? Well, the two media-queries (before, after) will work and change the color of the font to either `PaleTurquoise` and `red`. The one that is causing trouble is not changing its `font-color` to `lime`.

The strange part here is that if I add any other css to the troubling media-query, that particular css will work.

Why is this happening?

I've pasted the entire css here: [DPASTE - styles.css](http://dpaste.org/IGXRz/)

I've pasted the entire HTML here: [DPASTE - index.html](http://dpaste.org/XyJah/#L16)

I'm also using the [Erik Meyers reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Not that it matters, but is there a reason for the inconsistent use of media types `all` and `only screen` in your code?

Comment: Your rep and question/answer history shows you're familiar with how SO works, but you've provided no demo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the second media-query you want to set the **font**-color to lime?

currenty you are setting the **background**-color.

try this one:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1190px) and (max-width: 1409px) {
    body {
        color: lime;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was just a typo after testing around, sorry for that. I've revised it. Have you run the code from my paste?

Comment: Basically any css applied to the body is neglected.

Comment: i downloaded all three snippets and meregd them. I'll get al lime colored text. that means it is working.

Comment: What do you mean by "all lime colored". Even when resizing your browser window?

Comment: when i have a screen size between 1190 and 1409 px. i always get the correct color

Comment: It was an encoding error, between the body and the `{` there was a strange ascii char. Removed it and it worked! Thanks for the help! :)